# Internet explorer compability? Javascript for each functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");
 
function toggleAccordion(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
}
 
items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

this is the javaScript code I have for opening the accordions in a FAQ question tab. Internet explorer logs in to my console error when I use this but modern browsers don't(edge, chrome, firefox ). How can I get over this issue? The project requires internet explorer compability.

Comment: Error, what is the error message?

Comment: What versions of Internet explorer do you need to be compatible with? (we'll assume IE11 if you don't specify, since that's the only version still supported, but it's helpful to be clear about these things)

Comment: IE (even IE11) does not support the ES6 syntax for Javascript. This includes `const` and `forEach`. You'll need to change at least those two parts of your code.

Comment: IE console logs this error "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error" and points it to the forEach function. also yes IE11.

Comment: @Spudley IE11 recognizes `const` keyword, but treates it like `var` (block scope/constant is not "created").

Comment: @Teemu re `const` it's easier to just treat it as not supported than try to grapple with the same code working differently for different users, and possibly in subtle ways that would be tough to debug.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: {   "message": "Syntax error",   "filename":
>   "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 19,   "colno": 21 }

Fat arrow functions are [not supported in any version of IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

Use ES5 classic functions instead.

```
items.forEach(function(item) { item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion) });
```

Comment: tried this but internet explorer is logging the error "Line: 9
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'"

Comment: what about `for( var item of items)` ?

Comment: @hateScala NodeList in IE doesn't support `forEach` method. You've to either convert the list object to array, or use a regular `for` loop instead of  `forEach` (`for .. of` is not supported either).

Comment: ES5 syntax says for in is supported. But when `for .. in` was used it says object does not support event listeners. but still works in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) and `forEach` on NodeList. The return value of `querySelectorAll` is a NodeList.

We can transpile es6 syntax like arrow functions to es5 using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) and polyfill `forEach` to make it compatible with IE 11.

**Polyfill:**

```
var ctors = [typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList, typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" && HTMLCollection];     
        for (var n = 0; n < ctors.length; ++n) {     
            var ctor = ctors[n];     
            if (ctor && ctor.prototype && !ctor.prototype.forEach) {        
                ctor.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;     
                if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol.iterator && !ctor.prototype[Symbol.iterator]) {     
                    Object.defineProperty(ctor.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {     
                        value: Array.prototype[Symbol.itereator],     
                        writable: true,     
                        configurable: true     
                    });     
                }     
            }     
        }
```

**es6 to es5:**

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");

function toggleAccordion() {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(function (item) {
  return item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion);
});
```